# ObjCMongoDB framework and SyncServices in OSX

Tags: objective-c, mongodb, core-data, objcmongodb

I'm looking for some pointers on how to keep a CoreData model in sync with a MongoDB.  I'm leveraging the ObjCMongoDB framework and I can create objects in core data as follows:

```
coreDataObj = [BSONDecoder decodeManagedObjectWithClass:[Hostname class]
                                                context:[self managedObjectContext]
                                                   data:[bson_host dataValue]];
```

Unfortunately when you re-import the MongoDB a copy of the same objects is made and stored.

I'm not sure if I am using the ObjCMongoDB framework incorrectly or if I need to be using SyncServices to import data into my coredata model?

Can someone guide me or provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjCMongoDB (of which I'm author) performs deserialization to Core Data, but, at present, not deduplication or syncing. It treats BSON documents as simple ordered dictionaries, without a sense of an identification attribute. In particular, it treats `_id` like any other key.

You can get the behavior you want but you'll need to implement it yourself.

The easiest way would be to implement `-awakeAfterUsingCoder:` or `-awakeAfterUsingBSONDecoder:` – doesn't matter which – in your NSManagedObject subclass. The decoder will automatically invoke these.

`self` will be the new, deserialized object. Run a fetch request to look for an existing entry which `self` duplicates. If you find one, apply the properties to the existing object, delete the new object from the context, and return the existing entry. If you don't find one, simply return `self`.

You can use `-dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` and `-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` to accomplish this, and I usually get a list of keys with a method like this:

```
+ (NSArray *) persistentKeysForEntity:(NSEntityDescription *) entity {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSPropertyDescription *pdesc in [entity properties]) {
        if ([pdesc isTransient]) continue;
        [result addObject:pdesc.name];
    }
    return [result copy];
}
```

**Added:** If you don't need to exclude transient attributes, you can apply the values with one line:

```
[target setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:self.entity.attributesByName.allKeys]];
```